# Google Adsense clash with SSL certificate

Tags: jquery

When I add the below AdSense script to my SSL secure page it shows crossed red mark when browsed using chrome. When I remove this adsense script my SSL works great and perfect. Confused why the SSL does not accept even if I use https secure external link

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
```

Answer (score 1):

AdSense does not support SSL as of now. Been searching around for this myself, and as far as I can see, people have been requesting SSL for years, but Google has not yet given a date for when AdSense will support this.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some experimenting on this and the problem seems connected to image ads only.

From my experiments it seems to me that if you use the https prefix on the script you add to the page (as you do in the question) and set the ad unit type to 'Text' and not 'Image' or 'Image/Text' then you do not get the warnings (at least not in Chrome).

You should be able to override the adsense attribute by using the the tags specified here:

http://support.google.com/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=90779

So, you should be able to conditionally add this override if https is detected as the delivery protocol. I am going to look into doing this on my pages very soon - I'll update this question with the code once I have.

Comment: Scratch that... I just got the warning again even with just Text only ads. I just didnt experiment long enough :-(

Comment: Actually that warning seems to be triggered from the Google+1 button I added to the page - not the adsense script - so maybe this is a valid solution after all. More experiments needed....